# Add event listener to the document versus check in element exists and then add event listener

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

I've been looking for this but I haven't found an answer.
I was wondering which is a better practice in Javascript. To add an event listener that will only work if target is the desired one:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains('foo')){
                
     }
});
```

or to create a variable referring to the desired element and if this exists add the event listener

```
var a = document.querySelector('.foo');

if (a) {
    a.addEventListener('click', function(){

    })
}
```

Comment: The second one will not affect elements added after you call querySelector.

Comment: it depends on what you want/need to do, both ways have pro and cons. with faster browsers now common, the late filtering of delegation is not as large of a performance impact as before, and so you see more and more of the first pattern these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always choose the first aproach, because it affects dynamically created elements also. I also think you don't need the first part of the condition. My code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.id == "confirm-button"){
    // do something
  }
});
```